# Add quantiles to dataframe as multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, quantile

How can I most easily use pandas' .quantile function to add a column for each of multiple quantiles to a dataframe?

e.g. if my dataframe looks like:

```
1 A 10
1 B 1
2 A 6
2 C 13
3 D 15
3 G 1
```

I will get a row for each in the first column, with columns for each quantile like:

```
1 <Quantile 1> <Quantile 2>
2 <Quantile 1> <Quantile 2>
3 <Quantile 1> <Quantile 2>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Setup**

```
df
   A  B   C
0  1  A  10
1  1  B   1
2  2  A   6
3  2  C  13
4  3  D  15
5  3  G   1
```

Perhaps a `groupby.quantile` followed by `unstack` is what you're looking for.

```
df.groupby('A')['C'].quantile([.25, .5, .75]).unstack()

   0.25  0.50   0.75
A                   
1  3.25   5.5   7.75
2  7.75   9.5  11.25
3  4.50   8.0  11.50
```

Comment: This works, but I noticed when I try to do this using .agg() instead, I get a weird error:

AttributeError: 'Float64Index' object has no attribute 'labels'

Comment: @BirdLaw Not sure you can do it with agg :-(

Answer (score 2):

We can using `describe`

```
df.groupby('A').C.describe()[['25%','50%','75%']]
Out[1245]: 
    25%  50%    75%
A                  
1  3.25  5.5   7.75
2  7.75  9.5  11.25
3  4.50  8.0  11.50
```